# Testing two expects of same function using one 'it'

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am new to Jasmine. I have faced this particular issue as follows: -
Let's suppose the code i want to test is:

```
myTestFunction: function () {
  if (this.field) {
    return true;
  }
  else
     return false;
}
```

TestCase:

```
it('myTestFunction', function () {
   this.obj.field = true;
   expect(obj.myTestFunction() ).toEqual(true);
   this.obj.field = false;
   expect(obj.myTestFunction() ).toEqual(false);
})
```

Now if my first `expect` fails, the whole test case fails and my other `expect` are not even considered. Is there any way that if one of the expect fails, the other works fine and test case shows one expect to be failed and other to be passed, without writing seperate test cases for if and else ?
Thank you

Comment: Each `it` should be a separate case. So, if you want to test the `true` and `false` variants separately, you can't have them in the same `it`.

Comment: Cerbrus is right. This really should be two separate test cases. It doesn't matter how many `expect`s you put in each `it` block. If one of them fails the whole test fails.

Answer (score 1):

Each `it` should be a separate case. So, if you want to test the true and false variants separately, you can't have them in the same `it`:

```
it('myTestFunction true', function () {
  this.obj.field = true;
  expect(obj.myTestFunction() ).toEqual(true);
})

it('myTestFunction false', function () {
  this.obj.field = false;
  expect(obj.myTestFunction() ).toEqual(false);
})
```